# Get images from gallery in taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

There seems to be several answers to similar questions but I have not yet found one working for me.

I  have a custom post-type called `entertainement`. `entertainement` has a taxonomy called `ent_categories`.

One of the `ent_categories` is called `Event`

Each `Event` has a gallery and I am trying to make a query that will return the latest 10 images that has been added to any of the CPT `entertainment` with the category `Event`.

Im hoping to receive a list of urls in an array.

From what I read here something like this should do the trick:

```
$arg = array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
);


$arg['tax_query'] = array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'ent_categories',
    'field' => 'name',
    'terms' => array( 'Event' ),

),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $arg );
var_dump($the_query);
```

The `var_dump($the_query);` displays a lot of things but no images?
Any tips on this one?
Thank you

EDIT:

I just saw that I can do this:

```
 function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {
   global $post;
    // Only do this on singular items
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return $content;
    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return $content;
    // Retrieve all galleries of this post
    $galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );
    $image_list = '<ul>';
    // Loop through all galleries found
    foreach( $galleries as $gallery ) {
        // Loop through each image in each gallery
        foreach( $gallery as $image ) {
            $image_list .= '<li>' . $image . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $image_list .= '</ul>';
    // Append our image list to the content of our post
    $content .= $image_list;
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );
```

This result in that all the gallery images urls get displayed below the images in the gallery.
Maybe this function could be called from a page instead than from functions.php?

Comment: What do you mean by _Each `Event` has a gallery_? Do you mean an ACF's Gallery Field?

Comment: Thank you for answering. No, not ACF galleryfield. The gallery is added as a shortcode using the "standard" wordpress gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you're querying for posts of type `attachment` with a `term` of the `ent_categories` taxonomy which only applies to `entertainement` posts, so there won't be any of them as you'll see if you:

```
var_dump($the_query->posts);
```

> If you dump all `$the_query` you'll see *lots of things* because it's a `WP_Query` object.

You need to query your `entertainement` posts: (**Be careful  because you have a typo in your slug!**)

```
$arg = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'entertainement',
);


$arg['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ent_categories',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'Event',

    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $arg );
```

Then you can iterate the posts and get the gallery items like this:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if (get_post_gallery()) :
            echo get_post_gallery();
            print_r(get_post_gallery_images());
        endif;
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

[`get_post_gallery_images()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images) will get you an array of the URL's of gallery images

[`get_post_gallery()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images) will get you actual HTML to print the gallery.

Comment: Thank you very much for a working solution and a great explanation!